# Installing a bz2 file

Tags: fedora, software-installation, executable, 32bit

Coming from a windows platform I am a bit confused over how compressed files are installed in Linux . I am using fedora 20.
Now I downloaded FoxIt pdf reader from [here](http://cdn02.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/reader/desktop/linux/1.x/1.1/enu/FoxitReader-1.1.0.tar.bz2). I also read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) post which explains what to do with compressed files.However I am still confused as to what to do when a the bz2 file is uncompressed. The read me file states

> 2. For Tar package installation, please note that the "fpdfcjk.bin" file has to be put into the same directory where the "FoxitReader"
>      file is and also your system has to support displaying Chinese, Korean
>      and Japanese normally, so that PDF files containing
>      Chinese/Japanese/Korean fonts can be properly displayed.

This is what I get

```
[op@localhost Downloads]$ ls
1.1-release  FoxitReader-1.1.0.tar.bz2  
[op@localhost Downloads]$ cd 1.1-release/
[op@localhost 1.1-release]$ ls
FoxitReader  fpdfcjk.bin  fum.fhd  po  Readme.txt
[op@localhost 1.1-release]$ ./FoxitReader 
bash: ./FoxitReader: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
[op@localhost 1.1-release]$
```

Any suggestions on what I should be doing when a bz2 file is extracted ?
I also know i could probably download this through yum but I would really like to do this the way of extracting a compressed file.Any suggestions on tackling this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error (likely) means you are trying to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system. I'll answer the specific issue here, but **see the bottom of the answer for the better approach in general**. You say have `yum` around, so this may help you:

```
yum install lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

`yum` will try to find anything that provides that file and then install it. It should find `glibc.i686`, so you can jump right to that with:

```
yum install glibc.i686
```

You may well find that you need other libraries too. This will be a "multilib" setup; you should look into what that will involve for your particular distribution.

---

> I also know i could probably download this through yum but I would really like to do this the way of extracting a compressed file.

You will almost always be better off installing software with the package manager (that's what it's for!), rather than extracting random executables off the internet. Try to wean yourself off this approach in general - it's often just not going to work, and even when it does it's suboptimal.

In this case in particular the software may not be in the package repository, so that option may not be available, but **note that there is an "RPM" download option** on the website you got it from. RPM is the package format used on your distribution. This will almost certainly be a better option than the tarball, so I suggest trying that instead. Install that file with:

```
rpm -ivh foxit.rpm
```

substituting your own filename. The package manager will be able to give you more information and help you more, even though it wasn't from one of the distribution repositories.

Answer (score 1):

This code works on Debian Distro.

1. First of all download or locate your bz2 file.
   example:
2. ```
    cd /desktop/yourfile_here
   ```
3. ```
    tar -xvjf yourfile
   ```
4. ```
    cd ./directory_created
   ```
5. ```
    ./configure
   ```
6. ```
    sudo make
   ```
7. ```
    sudo make install
   ```

Comment: Don't vote down, not this answer is lowlevel, but the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of installing a package in Linux/Unix.

1. Installing using package managers like `apt` or `rpm`.
2. Compiling the package from source code and installing them. These packages are compressed archives.
3. Binary packages that come with an installation script or you might directly need to copy the binaries to appropriate location. These too come in compressed archives.

Here the package you are trying to install belongs to the third category. Follow below steps to install the package.

```
$ tar -xavf FoxitReader-1.1.0.tar.bz2
$ cd 1.1-release/
$ ls
FoxitReader  fpdfcjk.bin  fum.fhd  po  Readme.txt

$ ./FoxitReader
```

The last command should start the application.

Comment: This doesn't really address the concrete issues in the question. We already know that it doesn't work.